# HttpBasic authentication failure url

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am using Spring Boot and Angularjs. I am using `HttpBasic` for security. I want the user to be redirected to a particular url on authentication failure or when session is expired.

The problem I am experiencing is the browser keeps poping up the authentication dialog when either the session is expired or a protected resource is visited by an authorized user.

Here is my `SecurityConfiguration`

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/login.html", "/templates/forgotpassword", "/user/forgot-password", "/user/reset-password", "/reset-password/**", "/custom/**", "/app/**", "/", "/user", "/logout", "/css/**", "/api/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
```

loginPage java-doc:

> Specifies the URL to send users to if login is required. If used with
>   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter a default login page will be generated
>   when this attribute is not specified.